# Apache Mahout- exception with file.csv

Tags: java, apache, exception, machine-learning, mahout

I'm new in Apache Mahout. I want to classify a .csv file
The columns of this file are id,AAAA,.....TTTT,species
and values of each record are ebolavirus1,123,434,34,34,322,1,1,333,4,555,zaire.
I want to classify species(ex zaire,sudan,tai forest ebolavirus.

When I try to run my code, it gives me the following exception :

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong numLabels: 0. Must be > 0!

I follow these steps :

./mahout seqdirectory --input input/labelOutput.csv --output target/out

./mahout seq2sparse --input target/out --output target/vectors

./mahout trainnb -i target/vectors/tfidf-vectors -o target/final --li target/labelIndex

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your csv file for whether it has empty rows or not.